# Capture the status code netcat is returning (500, 503, 402, etc.) and add to a message

Tags: bash

How do I make this script to capture the type of error it is returning (500,503,402, etc) and add that in the message?

```
#!/bin/bash
hostlist=(s-example1.us s-example2.us)
for host in "${hostlist[@]}"; do
    if nc -w 2 -z $host 80; then
        echo "INFO: ssh on $host responding [Looks Good]"
    else
        echo "ERROR: ssh on $host not responding[Ooops something went wrong]"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to capture the output in a variable, and then condition the message based on matching of 500,503,402:

```
test=$(nc -w 2 -z $host 80)
if [[ -n $(grep '500\|503\|402' <<< $test) ]]; then
   ...
else
   echo ok
fi
```

Comment: The exit status can't be higher than 255.

Comment: You always have my back. I have corrected my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To check the HTTP status codes of websites, I would recommend to use `curl` instead if you can:

```
#!/bin/bash
hostlist=(s-example1.us s-example2.us)
for host in "${hostlist[@]}"; do
    status=$(curl -sLI -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" "$host")
    case "$status" in
    200) echo "INFO: ssh on $host responding [Looks Good]" ;;
    *) echo "ERROR: $host responded with $status" ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Perfect

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using cURL for this.

Something like this would give you just the status code for whatever endpoint you're hitting. This will output the response code from each host, and if the response code is invalid (000) it will return the failed response code in another message.

**CODE:**

```
#!/bin/bash
hosts=(fliggerfloffin.com google.com)

for host in ${hosts[@]}; do
    code=$(curl -m 2 -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" ${host})
    if [[ -z $code ]]; then
        printf "%s\n" "Missing response code from host"
        exit 1
    fi
    if (( $code == 000 )); then
        code="FAILURE"
    fi

    printf "%s\n" "HOST: [$host]     STATUS: [${code}]"
done
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
dumbledore@ansible1a [OPS]:~ > bash test.sh
HOST: [fliggerfloffin.com]     STATUS: [FAILURE]
HOST: [google.com]     STATUS: [301]
```